# Prevent top most windows form from grabbing focus during ui update

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a windows application (devexpress) where I open a top most form from the main form. A timer reloads the grid on that form every 10 secs. Every time the grid reloads, the form grabs the focus from the main form.

How can I prevent this from happening?

I tried override the ShowWithoutActivation but it doesn't help as i think the grid (or other controls) grabs the focus from the main form.
Maybe important, when i reload the grid, i update few different controls on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The focus grabbed by my form when i send it to front which i did every 10secs. I got rid of that part and it works.